# Change VPN config file after change of internet connection

Tags: vpn, openvpn, debian

I have a question regarding VPN setup, specifically, the setup of OpenVPN. An associate of mine has configured a remote computer (running headless Debian) to be able to connect to this device remotely, through VPN. Before, the setup consisted of a 3G/4G-dongle connected directly to the device.

Now, the physical setup has changed so that the device is connected to a wireless router.

My question is: does the VPN-configuration on the device need to change because of the change in the network settings?

Since I didn't do the setup myself, I'm not sure how they were made, so I won't be able to ask specific questions about that.

Also, I'm fairly new to VPN-setup, so please bear with me.

Regards

/S

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about Home networking are off-topic here, as a re product or resource recommendations. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Comment: I think the VPN config is not affected. You do need to make sure the wifi router does the port forwarding right, so you can reach your device.

Comment: This depends on the actual configuration which is unknown to us. Also, like already said in a comment, this is off-topic here.